# Wordpress Blogs - IP Address Assignment

Tags: wordpress, blogs, ip-address

I have this inquisitive doubt of how dedicated IP Addresses are assigned for each and every blog site created using Wordpress. Does WordPress allocate separate servers for every blog (which sounds silly) or do they use any sort of redirecting technique?

Comment: I don think they have dedicated ip's for each blob in the first place

Comment: Look for something called as shared hosting and you would realize how wordpress does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an HTTP/1.1 request, the browser sends the hostname (www.example.com) to the webserver in the headers. The server then takes that hostname and routes it to the appropriate configuration for that host.

This results in a single web server, on a single IP address, to host multiple domains.

The way wordpress does it is most likely much more complex, but this should give you an idea of how it's done.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting

Comment: You made my day! Thank you very much for the info..So to sum up, Wordpress uses IP Based Virtual Hosting...

Comment: Glad I could help :) If you have any more questions, ask away.